# how to print command arguments in Getopt::Long getoptions

Tags: perl, getopt

I am attempting to log behavior in my Perl script.  I would like to print all arguments that are passed to Getopt::Long's `GetOptions` but `@ARGV` is empty.

I would like something that would automatically print all options and their values that were passed to `GetOptions`.  I have been reading https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html but I can't find anything there.

What I want is very simple, I'm surprised that I can't find anything like this.
How can I automatically output all options and their settings for logging purposes?

Comment: Just save `@ARGV` before calling `GetOptions()`.

Comment: Calling GetOptions will remove all parsed options from `@ARGV`.

Comment: So, you want a autogenerated `usage` message?

Comment: @Holli I wanted to get the current state of the program for logging purposes.  But Hakon is correct, I can do this by saving @ARGV before calling `GetOptions`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the value of a variable before it gets changed, you make a copy of the value of the variable before it gets changed.

```
my @orig_ARGV = @ARGV;
```